# Formula for a Function $f(x)$ that Returns $0$ if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $1$ Otherwise

Tags: functions

Just like the question, I would like a formula for a function (elementary if possible, though not required) $f(x)$, that is $0$ if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $1$ (or any other constant $\geq 1$) otherwise.

Comment: It's the characteristic function of $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Z$. There are notations for this, such as $\chi_{\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Z}$ or ${\Bbb 1}_{\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Z}$.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x \in \mathbb{Z} \\ 1 & x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Z} \end{cases}$$

Comment: @Ryan Well, that's why I specified "formula" to prevent that misunderstanding.

Comment: @DUO And is there a reason you don't want that kind of description? It is, by far, the clearest way to describe your function.

Comment: @Arthur It's not exactly the best way to manipulate it the way I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use $f(x) = \lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor$. For $x \in \mathbb Z$ the two terms are equal and thus cancel out while for $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z$ we have $\lceil x \rceil = 1 + \lfloor x \rfloor$ and thus
$$ \lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor = 1 + \lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=1-\lfloor\cos(\pi x)^2\rfloor$, then $f(x)\in\{0,1\}$ and $f(x)=0\iff\cos(\pi x)\in\{-1,1\}\iff x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\lceil{|\sin(\pi x)|}\rceil$ where $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ is the [ceiling function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CeilingFunction.html).